# Detect connectivity on an ethernet port

Tags: networking, ethernet

Are the LED's on an ethernet port still the standard way of detecting network connectivity for ICT professionals in a professional environment?

We are designing an enclosure for a device in a professional / office environment. We are faced with having the back of the device look neatly organised but losing the LED's on the ethernet port, or having the ethernet port at a relatively weird place and keeping the LED's. So what I need is some insight in the relative importance of the LED's for detecting network connectivity for ICT professionals. Are they (still) the first thing they look at to troubleshoot a faulty connection, or are there other ways? Personal insights are very much appreciated, references to sources even more.

Comment: First thing to look at? No... Network management software will be the fist indicator. SNMP is still widely used for this function, giving the I.T department an indication of link failure within milliseconds of the link disco event

Comment: Why do you have to change your layout to have LEDs? Can't you use the kind of Ethernet receptacle that has the LEDs built into the corners of the RJ-45 female connector?

Comment: @Spiff, that is exactly the thing. I can, but the placement of the ethernet port on 'the motherboard' in the device will put the ethernet port at an awkward place on the device.

Answer (score 1):

The LED can be a valuable confirmation.

Depending on your network card, it might have useful significance.

These might exist as one or more LEDs :

- **Link light** indicates whether a network connection exists between the card and the network. An unlit link light is an indicator that something is wrong with the network cable or connection.
- **Activity light** indicates network activity. Under normal conditions, the light should flicker sporadically and often. Constant flickering may indicate a very busy network or a problem somewhere on the network that is worth investigating.
- **Speed light** indicates that the interface is connected at a certain speed. This feature is deprecated and is more normally found on Ethernet NICs that operate at 10Mbps/100Mbps.